# Sync setup of Ubuntu servers?

Tags: apt, sync

I have a couple of Ubuntu servers, which all have the exact same setup besides the hostname. I was wondering what would be the best way to sync the config of those servers?

The following stuff needs to be synced:

- list of installed packages
- few configuration files in /etc

I'm aware of things like Puppet or Chef, but they seem to be overkill for what I want to achieve. Isn't there a simple built-in solution in Ubuntu to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you had a look at [stipple](https://launchpad.net/stipple) and [oneconf](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/OneConf/)?

They seem to take care of the basics. For anything not covered there, you may want to use rsync or [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) (both can work over ssh; unison actually uses rsync for the trasfer, iirc).

Comment: I had a brief look, but as far as I understand, those tools are based on Ubuntu One, which in turn would require a desktop. But my servers don't have a desktop environment installed. So I haven't taken a deeper look at those.

Answer (score 1):

I've not tried it, but some people at my work use [csync2](http://oss.linbit.com/csync2/).

For a lighter solution, you could also use `cssh` to type in your commands in parallel across all of your servers.
The package name is `clusterssh`. In order to connect in parallel, enter these commands:

```
cssh root@server1 root@server2 ...
```

Comment: I like the cssh idea. I will investigate it!